# web config transform How to transform two connection strings into one using config transform?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web-config-transform

I have two databases in my MVC 5 application. One is the memmbership database and the other is the application database. I want to merge the databases into one database
and set the destination database for the both databases the same in the project's Package/Publich SQL property. I also created a config transform for the web.config file.
This is how it looks.

```
    <connectionStrings>
          <add name="DefaultConnection" 
    connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-0CKI1SE;Initial Catalog=DT;User ID=test;Password=test1234"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
          <add name="DriversTrainingEntities"
   connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-0CKI1SE;Initial Catalog=DT;User ID=test;Password=test1234"
   xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

After Deploying the application, The schema is created perfectly for the membership database DefaultConnection. But for the application database, I get  the error
"Keyword not supported:'data source'". I think this is because I added the connection string for the destination database twice. How can I change the configuration for 
both databases only once?